# Why does adding a type before a hash variable that is being built with fat arrow syntax, lead to type check failed error?

Tags: hash, raku

Raku is [gradual typing](https://docs.raku.org/language/glossary#index-entry-gradual_typing) language. So the code below:

```
my %hash = abc => 4.5, abd => 5.5, bcd => 6.4, bce => 3.6;
```

is the same as:

```
my Hash %hash = abc => 4.5, abd => 5.5, bcd => 6.4, bce => 3.6;
```

However, it reports an error:

```
Type check failed in assignment to %hash; expected Hash but got Rat (4.5)
```

Why adding a type before a hash variable that build with fat arrow syntax leaded to type check failed error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you say `my Hash %hash`, you're specifying a `Hash` that will only take `Hash` as a **value**.  And in your example, you're putting `Rat`s into the hash as values, not `Hash`es.  Which is what the error message is trying to tell you.

Your example would make more sense this way:

```
my Numeric %hash = abc => 4.5, abd => 5.5, bcd => 6.4, bce => 3.6;
```

in which you force all *values* to be `Numeric`.

Another way of writing that, is:

```
my %hash is Hash[Numeric] = abc => 4.5, abd => 5.5, bcd => 6.4, bce => 3.6;
```

The first way is just syntactic sugar for the second.

If you **also** want to limit the keys, there are also two ways to do that:

```
my %hash is Hash[Numeric,Str] = abc => 4.5, abd => 5.5, bcd => 6.4, bce => 3.6;
```

would limit the keys to `Str`.  Note that by default, the type is `Str()`, aka: **coerce** anything to `Str`, which is **not** the same.

The more syntactic sugary way is:

```
my Numeric %hash{Str} = abc => 4.5, abd => 5.5, bcd => 6.4, bce => 3.6;
```

which I think, *is* more readable as it is clear what the typing of the keys is.

Comment: I used to writing type annotations like this in Scala: `val map: Map[String, Double] = Map("abc" -> 4.5, "abd" -> 5.5, "bcd" -> 6.4, "bce" -> 3.6)`, and I get confused when shift to Raku. Thank you for clearing my confusion!

Comment: Added some explanation of more Scala-like ways.